# Bluemix (IBM CLoud) can't manage access to cloudfoundry orgs/spaces in USsouth and Germany

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We can't anymore manage user access in cloud foundry spaces/orgs anymore from us and germany.. in UK we can delete users...
So the "add user" button are gone... Please advice on how to set user permissions in CF org's and spaces

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to access the Identity & Access Management

https://console.bluemix.net/iam/

Select the user you want to give access, click the name, it will send you to the ["Manage User"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xs0P.jpg).

In this screen you can assign a new organization to the user, assign new permissions to the organization and give permissions to any space belonging to those organizations.

If the questions was more about the creation of new users, then you need to click on ["+invite users"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ut9b.jpg) in the IAM screen. In the [invite users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zImEX.jpg) screen, you can also define all permissions the new user will have.

Comment: Tanx - just a bit confused that the old way - manage organizations -Cloud Foundry org - users did not work anymore in Germany and US...